# Atualização personalizada para plugins WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Como eu faço para disponibilizar atualizações (*updates*) para um plugin WordPress que eu desenvolvi?
Dá pra fazer isso com o GitHub? Ou só é possível pelo [diretório oficial](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)?

Comment: ele está disponível onde? no repositório de plugins do wp?

Comment: Atualmente em lugar nenhum...

Comment: não entendi a sua pergunta... vc quer atualizar um plugin que nunca foi disponibilizado?

Comment: O plugin está rodando no site, mas gostaria de uma alternativa de poder, sempre que houver uma atualização, eu fazer um commit, ao inves de upar  os arquivo toda vez que altera-lo.

Comment: Dei uma caçada e encontrei isso aqui, veja se faz sentido pra vc: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-your-plugins-in-github-with-automatic-updates--wp-34817

Comment: Oi, Italo, dei um trato na sua pergunta para ajudar a quem for pesquisar no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vão as ferramentas que testei para fazer isso:

- [YahnisElsts/**wp-update-server**](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/wp-update-server)
  *A custom update API for WordPress plugins and themes. Intended to be used in conjunction with my plugin-update-checker library.*
- [thomasgriffin/**TGM-Updater**](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Updater)
  *This class has been tested and works with both regular and Multisite installs, and it even works with services like ManageWP!*
- [YahnisElsts/**plugin-update-checker**](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker)
  *A custom update checker for WordPress plugins. Ufseful if you can't or don't want to host your plugin in the official WP plugin repository, but would still like it to support automatic plugin updates.*
- [jeremyclark13/**automatic-theme-plugin-update**](https://github.com/jeremyclark13/automatic-theme-plugin-update)
  *Self hosted plugin and theme update scripts*

A que terminei usando foi a do Yahnis Elsts, mas usei para *updates* direto no meu servidor. Acho que para GitHub tem que ser outra. Precisa testar o que funciona melhor no seu caso.